# Symfony Inyección Vs Instancia

Tags: php, symfony3, symfony

Hola Tengo una Buena Duda.

Tenemos Clase definida (**ClaseA**) y servicios (ServB, ServA...)
Estos Servicios utilizan esta clase "**ClaseA**", que pasa que esta **ClaseA** puede Definirse como servicio tambien por ejemplo; entonces tenemos lo siguiente:

El **ServA** Requiere de los serivicios A, B y **ClaseA** pero **ClaseA** Puede Instanciarse como new **ClaseA();**  o Bien podría inyectarse como servicio en el construcctor del **ServA**, y del **ServB**, y **ServC** ETC y asi digamos X servicios más.

En cuanto a rendimiento ¿sería mejor para los servicios, que la instancia de **ClaseA** este dentro como inyección  o bien como una instancia de la new **ClaseA()**?...

Entiendo en este caso (si no me falla la teoría) que si lo hago como new **ClaseA()** cada vez que requiera el servicio será un objeto nuevo con su respectiva carga de memoria etc, etc, etc.. para cada servicio si hay 3 servicios que lo usan serán 3 objetos nuevos diferentes en cada uno con su respectiva carga de memoria, PERO, ocurre lo mismo si es injectado? o es menor la carga de memoria, esa parte la he estado tratando de entender y no me queda claro.!!!

Ayudadme a subir mi Level Gurú SF!! 
Gracias!!!

Comment: En esta pregunta me refería específicamente a clases cuyas instancias no requiere parámetros del constructor, lo que quiere decir que pueden declararse como servicio o bien dentro de uno o varios servicios que los utilicen, la ventaja que veo es que al no requerir parámetros, las puedes instanciar donde lo necesites sin necesidad de crearlo como servicio, así no lo injectas a otros servicios simplemente lo instancias y lo usas; **por otro lado** si lo declaras e "_injectas_" tienes claro lo que usa ese servicio!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las inyecciones usan Lazy Loading, por tanto la eficiencia es la misma, el punto es que si das `new ClaseA()` y esa clase en el constructor tiene parámetros, también tendrás que pasárselo, por ejemplo

```
class ClaseA {

  private $claseB;

  public function __construct(ClaseB $claseB){
    $this->claseB = $claseB; 
  }
}
```

Para llamarlo tendrías que hacer algo como (con todo lo que la configuración trae consigo)

```
public function foo(){
  $b = new ClaseB();
  $a = new ClaseA($b);
}
```

En cambio, con inyección de dependencias puedes hacer algo como

```
public function foo(){

  $a = $this->get('AcmeBundle/ClaseA')->getFunction();
}
```

y obvias toda la configuración previa ya que la tienes definida en el servicio, y se asume que el requerimiento de ClaseB ya está configurado. Un ejemplo práctico son para tener los controladores como servicio, así tenemos una configuración como la siguiente.

```
# app/config/services.yml 
 services: 
      _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

      AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,EventListener,Extensions,Tests,Security,Events,Service}'

      AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
        calls:
          - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

además, supón que tu controlador es algo como esto

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// Entidades
use AppBundle\Entity\Usuario;
// Formulario
use AppBundle\Form\UsuarioType;

class UsuarioController extends Controller
{
  public function getAll(){
    $em            = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $usuarios      = $em->getRepository(Usuario::class)->findAll();

    return $usuarios;
  }
}
```

Ahora que está configurado el servicio y la inyección, puedes llamarlo desde cualquier parte que tenga el Container (por ejemplo, desde otro controlador) como:

```
$this->get(UsuarioController::class)->getAll()
```

Con esto el código queda más legible y desacoplado; ahora, desde el punto de vista de la eficiencia, no podría asegurar cuál de las formas sea más rápida ya que el container de symfony es compilados, los servicios son por lazy loading y se crea el mapeo cada vez que se inicializa el kernel.

Comment: Correcto lo que dices @h40s4m4 ciertamente la ventaja con la injección y delcararlo como servicio es que olvidas la parte del constructor, pero como mencione en la pregunta es mas que todo en caso que sean objetos simples sin parémetros en el constructor; ya que si los tienen la opción clara sería con los servicios, ya que te olvidas de los parámetros que ya se injectan. Gracias!!!